# Task Environment \end{task} error & math mode spacing error

Tags: amsmath, math-operators, tasks

There are 2 errors in the MWE I want to resolve.

1. in the enumerated #1 problem, I bolded the answer to right of equal sign. But that messed up the proper spacing after the = sign.

   $(12)\div 4 = $\boldmath$3$\unboldmath$
2. Final 2 lines of code `\task $7x^2-31x-20$ \end{tasks} causes this error:` unclosed $ found at \end{tasks}.

I've spent a couple of hours search tex stack forum without success.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}

\printanswers
% un-comment to print solutions.
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{}
%\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in,include head]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} % for "\scalebox" macro
\pagestyle{head}
\header{Algebra I Part 1}
       {}
       {10/14/22} 

\newcommand{\pagetop}{

\noindent 
  \fbox{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-4\fboxsep-4\fboxrule}{
    \textbf
    \bigskip
    
  }}}
  \bigskip
  \vspace{0.5mm}
}

\settasks{after-item-skip=1em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=1.5em, %<---------
          item-indent=2em,   %<---------
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=1em     %<----------
          }
% ------------ DOCUMENT STARTS HERE---------- %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

%definition for bigskip = 1 line to replace all \bigskip
\def\bigskip{\vskip\bigskipamount}
Write An Algebraic Expression and then evaluate. SHOW ALL WORK!\\
\bigskip
\centering\boldmath\scalebox{1.33}{$a=2$, $b=3$, $m=4$, $n=5$, $x=10$, $y=15$}\unboldmath
\bigskip
\begin{tasks}(2)
% Prob #1
\task the sum of $a$ and $x$ divided by $4$\\
\vspace{2mm}
$(a+x)\div 4$\\
\vspace{2mm}
$(2+10)\div 4$\\
\vspace{2mm}
$(12)\div 4 = $\boldmath$3$\unboldmath$
% Prob #2
\task $p^2-5p-14$
\vspace{5cm}
% Prob #3
\task $x^2-16x-63$
% Prob 4
\task $7x^2-31x-20$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A much more "direct" approach, one that doesn't require going in and out of math mode is `$(12)\div 4 = \mathbf{3}$`.  To correct the bad spacing, you could insert `{}` after the equal sign, but I'm not at all enthusiastic about the `\unboldmath`.

Comment: You have an odd number of `$` in your first task.

Comment: Question answered thanks to barbarabeeton and cgnieder. @barbarabeeton ...how do I bold out my variables without using `bold` and `unbold` (please see this code line: `\centering\boldmath\scalebox{1.33}{$a=2$, $b=3$, $m=4$, $n=5$, $x=10$, $y=15$}\unboldmath
\bigskip`  I'm trying to keep comma separators un-bolded.

Comment: @SiuslawMath -- I believe that using `\boldmath` is "scoped".  That is, if buried in a group, it goes away when the group is closed.  So wrapping your expression in `\bgroup \boldmath ... \egroup` should do the trick.  (Don't include `\centering` in the group if you want it to continue past that line.)  The commas should be unaffected since they're not within the math strings.